# Google Nearline Bucket Point in Time Clone

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had a Google Cloud Nearline bucket synced to my NAS. The NAS suffered data loss and it may have made its way up to the bucket. No versioning or logging was enabled so I have no way of knowing beyond modified timestamps and even if that is reliable it would only elude to corrupted data and not lost data.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to obtain a complete clone of the bucket from a specific date? As well as a log between two dates of what might have changed.

I tried contacting technical but it is so difficult that I have been unable to. Even after talking with general support for over 2 hours, they could not find a way to activate or upgrade my account support level to even ask the question to the relevant department.

Does anyone have an idea if getting a clone from a specific date is possible for Google Cloud technical?

Comment: Server Fault is not Google. Contact GCP directly for the support escalation part of your question.

Comment: Do you not have backups? Absent an offline copy or metadata, reconstructing missing and corrupt files will be extremely difficult.

Comment: GCP told me to post here and said that their technical support would 'see' it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this issue is very specific to your project the best course of action for a case like this is creating a Public Issue Tracker and through it you'll be able to provide all needed info to see what we can do.

I will make sure to take over your PIT request as soon as you create it and make sure to take the attention needed. (one of my colleagues or I will take over once you let us know)

So please follow the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to create a PIT, then leave a comment here and tag me letting me know of the PIT link.

Comment: Thank you @Waelmas, the PIT is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157060280).